# When will trigger 'Pointer authentication' crash?

Tags: ios, react-native

I get a crash by firebase. Only a useful information:

> Corrupt NSInvocation detected. Pointer authentication.

I didn't met this type of crash before. And I found this error is related to PAC, which means Pointer Authentication. And PAC is enabled from A12 clip. Thus all devices had this crash were from iPhone XR / 11 / 12 / 13 and so on.

Below is the crash file:

```
2022-02-07_16-44-57.4063_+0700-4c0b14a2bc46de636f18885059d3ef71e86671cd.crash
Incident Identifier: 3A24760C-2DD9-417C-AD49-DE29CD5DC9FF
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,6
Process:             ShopeeFood [27579]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/153DB199-A6C5-4237-A7C2-B2AB7F54D97B/ShopeeFood.app/ShopeeFood
Identifier:          vn.foody.DeliveryNow
Version:             5.11.1 (24)
AppStoreTools:       13C90b
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,6:15
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           vn.foody.DeliveryNow [3660]

Date/Time:           2022-02-07 16:44:57.4063 +0700
Launch Time:         2022-02-07 15:21:52.7331 +0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.2.1 (19C63)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.02.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000180a17f64
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [27579]

Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a17f64 _NSIPoisoned + 16 (NSForwarding.m:3059)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018094a1e8 -[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:] + 596 (NSForwarding.m:3068)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018091e9c4 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64 (NSForwarding.m:3474)
3   React                           0x000000010744b8dc -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
4   React                           0x000000010744da2c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 244 (RCTNativeModule.mm:114)
5   React                           0x000000010744d790 facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 44 (RCTNativeModule.mm:75)
6   React                           0x000000010744d790 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 88 (RCTNativeModule.mm:67)
7   React                           0x000000010744d5f0 facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 388 (RCTNativeModule.mm:80)
8   cxxreact                        0x0000000108932e70 facebook::react::JsToNativeBridge::callNativeModules(facebook::react::JSExecutor&, folly::dynamic&&, bool) + 152 (NativeToJsBridge.cpp:62)
9   jsireact                        0x0000000108acf1dc facebook::react::JSIExecutor::callNativeModules(facebook::jsi::Value const&, bool) + 92 (JSIExecutor.cpp:388)
10  jsireact                        0x0000000108ad132c facebook::react::JSIExecutor::initializeRuntime()::$_1::operator()(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) const + 8 (JSIExecutor.cpp:104)
11  jsireact                        0x0000000108ad132c decltype(std::__1::forward<facebook::react::JSIExecutor::initializeRuntime()::$_1&>(fp)(std::__1::forward<facebook::jsi::Runtime&>(fp0), std::__1::forward<facebook::jsi::Value const&>(fp0), std::__... + 28 (type_traits:3747)
12  jsireact                        0x0000000108ad132c facebook::jsi::Value std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<facebook::jsi::Value>::__call<facebook::react::JSIExecutor::initializeRuntime()::$_1&, facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value cons... + 28 (__functional_base:317)
13  jsireact                        0x0000000108ad132c std::__1::__function::__alloc_func<facebook::react::JSIExecutor::initializeRuntime()::$_1, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::JSIExecutor::initializeRuntime()::$_1>, facebook::jsi::Value (faceboo... + 28 (functional:1553)
14  jsireact                        0x0000000108ad132c std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::JSIExecutor::initializeRuntime()::$_1, std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::JSIExecutor::initializeRuntime()::$_1>, facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi... + 44 (functional:1727)
15  jsi                             0x0000000108a7d804 std::__1::__function::__value_func<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>::operator()(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, face... + 28 (functional:1880)
16  jsi                             0x0000000108a7d804 std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>::operator()(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value... + 44 (functional:2555)
17  jsi                             0x0000000108a7d548 facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value cons... + 384 (JSCRuntime.cpp:1151)
18  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bc2352c JSC::JSCallbackObject<JSC::JSNonFinalObject>::callImpl(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::CallFrame*) + 468 (JSCallbackObjectFunctions.h:566)
19  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c3f13c4 JSC::LLInt::setUpCall(JSC::CallFrame*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 1736 (NativeFunction.h:50)
20  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bb7b7b0 llint_function_for_construct_arity_checkTagGateAfter + 144508
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bb7b70c llint_function_for_construct_arity_checkTagGateAfter + 144344
22  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bb7b7e0 llint_function_for_construct_arity_checkTagGateAfter + 144556
23  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bb7b70c llint_function_for_construct_arity_checkTagGateAfter + 144344
24  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bb7ba70 llint_function_for_construct_arity_checkTagGateAfter + 145212
25  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bb52028 vmEntryToJavaScriptTrampoline + 8
26  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c28c704 JSC::Interpreter::executeProgram(JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::JSObject*) + 12632 (JITCodeInlines.h:42)
27  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c568c28 JSC::evaluate(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, ***::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 272 (Completion.cpp:137)
28  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018bc19ae8 JSEvaluateScript + 724 (JSBase.cpp:53)
29  jsi                             0x0000000108a78b08 facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) + 292 (JSCRuntime.cpp:426)
30  jsireact                        0x0000000108ace460 facebook::react::JSIExecutor::loadBundle(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::_... + 328 (JSIExecutor.cpp:158)
31  cxxreact                        0x0000000108932310 facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::loadBundleSync(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry> >, std::__1::unique_ptr<faceb... + 152 (NativeToJsBridge.cpp:154)
32  cxxreact                        0x0000000108925a4c facebook::react::Instance::loadBundleSync(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::RAMBundleRegistry> >, std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::rea... + 164 (Instance.cpp:88)
33  cxxreact                        0x0000000108925c08 facebook::react::Instance::loadScriptFromString(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char,... + 72 (Instance.cpp:105)
34  React                           0x000000010742ff94 __51-[RCTCxxBridge executeApplicationScript:url:async:]_block_invoke + 684 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:1367)
35  React                           0x00000001074348bc std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const + 20 (functional:1880)
36  React                           0x00000001074348bc std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const + 20 (functional:2555)
37  React                           0x00000001074348bc facebook::react::tryAndReturnError(std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 40 (RCTCxxUtils.mm:74)
38  React                           0x0000000107429c38 -[RCTCxxBridge _tryAndHandleError:] + 100 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:275)
39  React                           0x000000010742fc80 -[RCTCxxBridge executeApplicationScript:url:async:] + 164 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:1346)
40  React                           0x000000010742fbd4 -[RCTCxxBridge executeApplicationScriptSync:url:] + 24 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:1341)
41  React                           0x000000010742d538 -[RCTCxxBridge executeSourceCode:sync:] + 164 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:941)
42  SHPReactNativeSDK               0x0000000107ec1d8c -[SHPRNContainer executePluginCode:] + 236 (SHPRNContainer.m:152)
43  SHPReactNativeSDK               0x0000000107ec15a4 -[SHPRNContainer loadPluginBundle:bundleLoadCompletion:] + 492 (SHPRNContainer.m:80)
44  SHPReactNativeSDK               0x0000000107ed5fd8 -[SHPRNModeReleaseStrategies loadPlugin:bundleName:pageName:bundleLoadCompletion:] + 188 (SHPRNModeStrategies.m:63)
45  SHPReactNativeSDK               0x0000000107ec3070 __72-[SHPRNContainerManager loadPluginBundle:pageName:bundleLoadCompletion:]_block_invoke + 364 (SHPRNContainerManager.m:163)
46  SHPReactNativeSDK               0x0000000107ec3544 __72-[SHPRNContainerManager loadPluginBundle:pageName:bundleLoadCompletion:]_block_invoke.119 + 144 (SHPRNContainerManager.m:203)
47  Foundation                      0x00000001820ffc10 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 348 (NSNotification.m:327)
48  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808d2f88 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28 (CFNotificationCenter.c:652)
49  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018096ec3c ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 52 (CFNotificationCenter.c:173)
50  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180941ff4 _CFXRegistrationPost + 456 (CFNotificationCenter.c:199)
51  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808e8df4 _CFXNotificationPost + 716 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1147)
52  Foundation                      0x00000001820e5f68 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 96 (NSNotification.m:560)
53  SHPReactNativeSDK               0x0000000107ec4394 __62-[SHPRNContainerManager createPreLoadContainerWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 88 (SHPRNContainerManager.m:346)
54  SHPReactNativeSDK               0x0000000107ec1b50 -[SHPRNContainer pluginJSLoaded:] + 128 (SHPRNContainer.m:124)
55  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808d2f88 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28 (CFNotificationCenter.c:652)
56  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018096ec3c ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 52 (CFNotificationCenter.c:173)
57  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180941ff4 _CFXRegistrationPost + 456 (CFNotificationCenter.c:199)
58  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808e8df4 _CFXNotificationPost + 716 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1147)
59  Foundation                      0x00000001820e5f68 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 96 (NSNotification.m:560)
60  React                           0x000000010742d7a4 __39-[RCTCxxBridge executeSourceCode:sync:]_block_invoke_2 + 200 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:928)
61  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805b1924 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
62  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805b3670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
63  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805c1b70 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 944 (inline_internal.h:2601)
64  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808f9d84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
65  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808b3f5c __CFRunLoopRun + 2540 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
66  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001808c7468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
67  GraphicsServices                0x000000019c45238c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
68  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183269088 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3493)
69  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182fe7958 UIApplicationMain + 2092 (UIApplication.m:5046)
70  ShopeeFood                      0x00000001043ed73c main + 152 (main.m:19)
71  dyld                            0x000000010536daa4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

Hope anyone can help me how to solve this problem, or give me any information about this type of crash.

Thank you very much.